# How to start Apache2 in any directory?

Tags: php, apache2

I'm an apache2 and PHP beginner.

With other servers I'm used to just running them like

`CoolServer /directory/to/my_website`

This is very useful when working on multiple different websites stored in multiple different directories.

But apache2 only seems to run for ONE directory that is explicitly listed in a `conf` file ( `/var/www/html` by default ).

Is there a way to just get apache2 to run like:

`apache2 /directory/to/website1`

`apache2 /another/directory/website2`

Comment: You can write a shell script to generate virtual hosts conf dynamically

Comment: See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP built-in web server. If you are using Windows OS then link PHP to your PATH. And, goto to your project's root folder, open command prompt, and type:-

```
php -S localhost:8000
```